# input and textbox outside of table

Tags: html, css

I am pretty new to CSS and I'm trying to learn on my own. I was trying to create a new topic form but I find myself with an input and textarea completely outside my table like so :
[image]

I don't know how to solve this problem and it's frustrating because it seems to be something so basic. Here is the code of my form :

```css
.body {
  background-color: darkred;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.newTopic tr {
  background-color: grey;
  color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
  height: 45px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(44, 44, 44);
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <form class="createTopic" method="POST">
    <table class="newTopic">
      <tr class="enTete">
        <th class="body">New Topic</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="title">Title</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="70" name="titleTopic" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Message</td>
        <td><textarea name="msgTopic" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7d0cgwpu/35/

Is this happening because I have 2 separate td inside my tr? Because when i try to change my "new topic" header length, it also changes my title and message box length but always puts the input and textarea outside of them.

Comment: They're not outside your table, your `th` doesn't reach across both cells because you only have one of then, and two `td`s. Use `colspan="2"` on the `th`.

Comment: since you said that you're new: consider to start over. Ok this sound harsher then I actually mean. Tables are for tabular content, not or styling purpose. The only place where a table might by used for styling purpose are e-mail templates that also do not allow the sue of CSS. If you want a table like layout, use `flex-box` or `css-grid` instead.

Comment: Oh man it was as simple as that... I'm truly sorry for the waste of your time and i'm truly grateful for your answer and yes, the link totally answers my question ! Thanks a lot

Comment: This is not a solution, just a recommendation. Use grid or flex layout instead of tables. You should only use tables for tabular data.

Comment: Ok I will try it again with flex-box or grid instead of tables. Thanks a lot for the advices

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
<div class=container>
  <form class="createTopic" method="POST">
    <table class="newTopic">
      <tr class="enTete">
        <th class="body">New Topic</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sujet">Title<br><input type="text" size="68" name="titleTopic"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Message<br><textarea name="msgTopic" rows="10" cols="70"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

or:

```
<div class=container>
  <form class="createTopic" method="POST">
    <table class="newTopic">
      <tr class="enTete">
        <th class="body">New Topic</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td class="sujet">
        <label>Title</label>
        <div>
          <input type="text" size="70" name="titleTopic"/>
        </div>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Message</label>
          <div>
            <textarea name="msgTopic" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```